# Match first occurrence of string between two strings in text

Tags: php, regex, string

**Problem**

I want to select the first contents between two strings. For example:

```
https://subdomain.domain.com/lobby/het/login?retUrl=https://subdomain.domain.com/lobby/het/responsible?retUrl=https://uat-api.domain.com/forms/authorise-client?retUrl=https://subdomain.domain.com/lobby/het/login?retUrl=https://subdomain.domain.com/lobby/het/testing?retUrl=https://uat-api.domain.com/forms/authorise-client?locale=en-GB&client_id=123&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://subdomain/rem/rep/sol.html&prompt=0&state=authorise-client
```

We can see in the above URL that the retUrl occurs many times.

**Question**

How can I select the contents of ONLY the first retUrl(bold in the above string) using a Regular Expression? So, we need the first string which begins with "retUrl=" and ends on the first occurrence of a ? after it. Is this even possible?

**Tries which failed**

```
(?=retUrl=)(.*\n?)(?=\?)
(retUrl=)(.*)$\?
```

Comment: I'm surprised you're not receiving any errors. You usually need to encode URLs when using them as query string parameters.

Comment: It is encoded. I have decoded it now to make the example clearer.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
/retUrl=([^\?]*)/
```

With `([^\?]*)` you can simply say get me everything until a question mark. So you can use the regex with `preg_match()` which will only give you the first match of that regex.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This solution is very close. Yet, it still contains the "retUrl=" in the selection. Even though this is easy to remove with PHP, is there any way this could be excluded from the same RegExp itself?

Comment: @DimitrisDamilos Do `print_r($matches);` on your match array from `preg_match()`. You probably look at the `$matches[0]` which contains the full match. `$matches[1]` should contain the first capturing group.

Comment: `$matches[1]` should contain the string without the "retUrl="?

Answer (score 1):

[`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) only finds the first match. So there you go.

By contrast, [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) finds all matches.